# Eclipse plugin for code generation

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-generation

I have several classes like in the following example:

```
abstract class AClass {
  boolean validate(){
    return true;
  }
}
```

When another class extends `AClass`, I do it like this:

```
class BClass extends AClass {
  @Override
  boolean validate() {
    if (!super.validate()) {
        return false;
    }
    // TODO validate
    return true;
  }
}
```

Is there an eclipse plugin that generates that code for me when I create a new class from the menu(File>New>Class)?
I'm thinking to use an annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface Code {
    String content();
}
```

And add it to the method:

```
abstract class AClass {
    @Code(content = "\tif (!super.validate()) {\r\n" 
        + "\t\treturn false;\r\n" 
        + "\t}\r\n" 
        + "\t// TODO validate\r\n"
        + "\treturn true;")
    boolean validate() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The plugin should look for the annotation and generate the code in the newly created class.

Comment: I think the real question here is why you need to implement the same method over and over again

Comment: @matt In the extended class, `// TODO validate` will be replaced with code that validates new fields added by that class.

Comment: so make `validate()` final, and make a new abstract method `doValidate()`?

Comment: That is just an example. I want some methods to have default code, and I could change it/add some more code later. The idea with the `validate` method, is that every class should call `super`, and if it's ok, it can continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to my request would be the following:

Create in a plugin another *"New class wizard"*, by extending `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard` (similar to the `NewClassCreationWizard` class) with a page that extends `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage` (like `NewClassWizardPage`)

Override `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage.createTypeMembers(IType, ImportsManager, IProgressMonitor)`

First, call to `createInheritedMethods` (like in `NewClassWizardPage`)

Then, `type.getMethods()` will give you the inherited methods from the superclass.

Check if a method from the resulted array has the desired annotation in the superclass (e.g. `@Code`). If it does, create the new method code, including it's declaration:

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
buf.append("@Override").append("\n");
buf.append(Modifier.toString(Modifier.PUBLIC) + " ");
buf.append(Signature.toString(method.getSignature(), method.getElementName(), method.getParameterNames(), false, true));
buf.append(" {").append("\n");
buf.append("// the code from the annotation\n");
buf.append("}");
```

Delete the current method:

```
method.delete(true, monitor);
```

Then add the method with the custom code:

```
type.createMethod(buf.toString(), null, true, monitor);
```

Now install the plugin, and when you create a new class with the wizard, the custom code for the methods will be automatically written there.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows -> Preferences, you can type in Java code templates.

You'll find code templates under Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates

On Eclipse 3.5, the pattern for class body is blank.  You can add your own pattern.

Here's the pattern for new Java files, to give you an idea what a pattern looks like.

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

Comment: I want that the generated code to be for *some* methods only, not for *all methods*.